# How to assign a list to an array after initializing in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm calling a function to change an array in C, say

```
int array[3] = {a, b, c}
```

to

```
array[3] = {d, e, f}
```

but, it gives me an error.  Is there another way to assign a bunch of values all at once like I can do upon initialization with the braces in C?

Comment: Nope, you can't assign a brace-enclosed initializer to an existing array. What you can do is embed the array in a `struct`. Assigning to a `struct` *is* allowed, even when it contains an array.

Comment: You can only initialize once, after that the best you can do is `memcpy()`. You can pass 3 new values as parameters to a function and loop assigning the values to each of the elements of the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't assign an array to another array in C. There's not much of a rationale why, it's simply how the language was designed.

Some alternatives:

- `struct` wrapper.

  ```
  typedef struct
  {
    int array [3];
  } arr_t;
  ...
  arr_t arr  = {a,b,c};
  arr_t arr2 = {d,e,f};
  arr = arr2;
  ```
- `memcpy`.

  ```
  int arr[3]  = {a,b,c};
  int arr2[3] = {d,e,f};
  memcpy(arr, arr2, sizeof arr);
  ```
- `memcpy` + compound literal.

  ```
   int arr[3] = {a,b,c};
   memcpy(arr, (int[]){d,e,f}, sizeof arr);
  ```

Comment: With C23 the last `memcpy` can be made more generic: `memcpy(arr, (typeof(arr)){d,e,f}, sizeof arr);`.

Answer (score -2):

You can reallocate memory of this array like this (C++):

```
int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3};
    delete[] arr;
    arr = new int[] { 4, 5, 6};
    return 0;
}
```

In pure C, you should use `malloc` and `free` instead of `new` and `delete`

Or either don't call delete if you don't want to completely destruct your first set of objects and just realloc memory with new

Comment: C++ answers to C questions are off-topic. Also, heap allocation is a bad idea for an array this small. You make the code needlessly slow for no reason.

Comment: You're also leaking memory